# Do any of us operate businesses that we can use as a platform to advertise on?

Tags: discussion, promotion

Are there any UI products or apps our membership owns, is a member of or has leverage with that we can use to promote StackExchange UI? Would the developers of these apps be interested in sponsorship agreements, for instance by placing a link to StackExchange UI within the ad space for their app?