# What UI communities are there out there that we could approach and ask to participate?

Tags: discussion, promotion

Similarly to [this question about business sponsorships](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89/do-any-of-us-operate-businesses-that-we-can-use-as-a-platform-to-advertise-on), what are some UI/UX communities, networks or mailing lists that we can approach? Why? How should we approach them and with what?

Answer (score 1):

There's a good list of local groups and professional organizations on [archive.uxnet.org](http://archive.uxnet.org/). You should also check [meetup.com](http://meetup.com) and see if there's a group in your area.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like HCI/Usability/Design researchers to be approached.

Comment: Cool, could you be specific about how to approach those communities? For instance, are there websites/forums we can start with? What about conferences/book clubs?